# Python list create

Tags: python

I need to receive the first element of a list with a command line argument, and 2nd element to be the value of the 1st element plus one, third element to be the value of the 2nd element plus 1 and so on.

For example:

```
$ python3 print_list5.py 6
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

$ python3 print_list5.py 0 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I think I can improve the code by using for loops, but I am not sure how to use it.

My code:

[image: My code]

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I suggest looking into a beginner tutorial for Python.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use for loops, use [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) instead

range will return an generator that generates values from an `initial_value` to a `final_value` increasing by a `step_value` on demand.

You can then convert this generator into a list which will execute the generation of the elements and give a list with the desired elements as a result.

```
first_elem = sys.argv[1]
n_elems = 5
print(list(range(first_elem, first_elem + n_elems)))
```

If you want the number of elements to also be a parameter do

```
first_elem = sys.argv[1]
n_elems = sys.argv[2]
print(list(range(first_elem, first_elem + n_elems)))
```

and then call your script as

```
$ python3 print_list5.py 2 5
```

where in this case 2 is the first element and 5 the number of elements

Answer (score 0):

This is the optimized solution, I use list comprehension works like a charm.
List comprehension creates a new list based on existing ones.

```
import sys
input_sys = int(sys.argv[1])
print([input_sys if i == input_sys else i for i in range(input_sys, input_sys + 5)])
```